# React - How to correctly get the current value of a date input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I am trying to compare two dates in React App but it seems I am struggling to get the current value of a date input.

I have two date inputs and the min property of the second one must be >= to the first one selected date.

[image]

To solve it, I have written the following code:

**Render:**

```
<div className='flex-children'>
  <span className='flex-line'>
    <label for='depart'><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Depart: </label>
    <input type='date' id='depart' value={this.state.depart} min={today} onChange={this.pickDepart} />
  </span>
  <span className='flex-line'>
  <label for='return'> Return: </label>
  <input type='date' id='return' value={this.state.returning} min={minReturn} onChange={this.pickReturn} />
  </span>
</div>
```

**State and functions:**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedFrom: '4',
            depart: depart,
            returning: returing
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

      }

    handleChange(event) {    
        this.setState({
            selectedFrom: event.target.selectedFrom,
            depart: event.target.depart,
            returing: event.target.return
            });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    pickDepart = (event) => {
        this.setState({depart: event.target.depart});
        setMinDate(event.target.depart);
    };

    pickReturn = (event) => {
        this.setState({returning: event.target.return});
    };
```

**And here all my date functions:**

```
function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}
  
function getToday(days){
    var today = new Date();
    var today_us = addDays(today, days)
    var dd = String(today_us.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today_us.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today_us.getFullYear();
    return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
};

var minReturn = getToday(0);
var depart = getToday(0);
var returing = getToday(21);
const today = getToday(0);


function setMinDate(d1){
    d1 = new Date(d1);
    var d2 = new Date(today);
    console.log(d1);
    console.log(d2);
    if (d1.getTime() >= d2.getTime()){
        minReturn = d1;
    }else{
        minReturn = today;
    }
}
```

The prints of the console.log are here:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In `d1` variable in `setMinDate` it's format string it's not support on the `new Date(d1)`. If i'm not wrong the `event.target.depart` have 'dd/mm/yyyy' format, which means `new Date()` can't convert your string to Date based on [w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) Date format input (ISO, short, long).

You cant convert that string date format with this function.

```
const convertDateStringFormat = (dateString) => {
  // dd/mm/yyyy convert to yyyy-mm-dd
  const _splitedDate = dateString.split("/");
  const convertedDate = `${_splitedDate[2]}-${_splitedDate[1]}-${_splitedDate[0]}`;
  return convertedDate;

}
```

To prevent ambiguity on same variable avoid repeating naming variable

```
function setMinDate(d1){
    //d1 = new Date(d1); (You can replace d1 with another name)
    let _d1 = new Date(d1)
    ....
}
```

Comment: It is doesn't help since d1 is undefined before it is transformed to date :-(

Comment: What value in `event.target.depart` inside `pickDepart ()`  function?

Comment: Why reformat the string then parse it as UTC? Simpler to just convert it to Date:`let [d, m, y] = dateString.split(/\D/); return new Date(y, m-1, d)`. :-)